# Aligning images horizontally with respect to another image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align some pictures perfectly according to their height while maintaining their ability to scale. I have made a column layout using floats in CSS. There are three columns and have equal width so they scale equally but I can't seem to make the images have optimal height so they all fit in their containers with equal height. The images in my middle column are flowing out.

```css
.section__banner-row {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.section__banner-row:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.section__banner-row::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.section__banner-row [class^="col-"] {
  float: left;
}

.section__banner-row [class^="col-"]:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.section__banner-row .col-1-of-2 {
  width: calc((99.9% - 1rem) / 2);
}

.section__banner-row .col-1-of-3 {
  width: calc((99.9% - 2 * 1rem) / 3);
}

.section__inside-banner {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}



.container-shadow-box {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}




.container-shadow-box img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.container-shadow-box:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.11);
}
```

```html
<div class="section__banner-row">

  <div class="col-1-of-3">
    <div class="container-shadow-box">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/FhQFN40/blog-masonry-01.jpg" alt="Masonry 1">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-1-of-3">
    <div class="container-shadow-box">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/0JHHwbm/blog-masonry-02.jpg" alt="Masonry 2">
    </div>

    <div class="section__inside-banner">
      <div class="col-1-of-2">
        <div class="container-shadow-box">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/NycZ9KN/blog-masonry-03.jpg" alt="Masonry 3">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-1-of-2">
        <div class="container-shadow-box">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/qRNZm1q/blog-masonry-04.jpg" alt="Masonry 4">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-1-of-3">
    <div class="container-shadow-box">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/PmcznpR/blog-masonry-05.jpg" alt="Masonry 5">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I don't know what browsers you have to support, but [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) might provide a much easier solution for this type of problem...

Comment: I hate to suggest scrapping your progress, but flexbox or CSS grid would be much more pleasant to work with. Floats are often unpredictable and rather archaic. Both alternatives would probably do away with the math, also.

Comment: I cant use CSS Grids. The only issue I have is with heights.

Comment: You're allowing your images to define height. That's problematic since you have various aspect ratios. Can they be set as backgrounds and cropped slightly?

Comment: Yes I can do that but would that be optimal ?

Comment: Actually, I think I can use CSS grids if that solution works in all latest browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox example:

```css
body * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid-box {
    padding-bottom: 28%; /* adjust this for container aspect ratio */
    height: 0;
    position: relative;
    background: pink;
}

.section__banner-row {
    display: flex;
}

.section__banner-row.outer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 5px;
}

.section__banner-row .col {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: stretch;
    align-items: stretch;
}

.section__banner-row .col > div {
    flex-basis: 50%;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.container-shadow-box {
    margin: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #ddd;
}

.container-shadow-box>div {
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-box">
    <div class="section__banner-row outer">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="container-shadow-box">
                <div style="background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/FhQFN40/blog-masonry-01.jpg);"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col">
            <div class="container-shadow-box">
                <div style="background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/0JHHwbm/blog-masonry-02.jpg);"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="section__banner-row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="container-shadow-box">
                        <div style="background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/NycZ9KN/blog-masonry-03.jpg);"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col">
                    <div class="container-shadow-box">
                        <div style="background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/qRNZm1q/blog-masonry-04.jpg);"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col">
            <div class="container-shadow-box">
                <div style="background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/PmcznpR/blog-masonry-05.jpg);"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/xz20ycme/40)

[Does my browser support flexbox?](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

Comment: But now the width of images cannot scale with the browser width. Can we add that functionality by maybe adjusting the background-size property ?

Comment: I think at this point, this would have something to do with aspect ratios but I cant seem to understand it.

Comment: Snippet and fiddle updated to use Bootstrap's responsive embed technique on the containing element.

Comment: Although the answer is already approved, I think it might still be valuable to put some context with your answer: what and why have you changed it? Others can benefit from that.